# Convert a list of bigram tuples to a list of strings

Tags: python, list, nlp, tuples, token

I am trying to create Bigram tokens of sentences.
I have a list of tuples such as

```
tuples = [('hello', 'my'), ('my', 'name'), ('name', 'is'), ('is', 'bob')]
```

and I was wondering if there is a way to convert it to a list using python, so it would look love this:

```
list = ['hello my', 'my name', 'name is', 'is bob']
```

thank you

Comment: have you tried anything at all? Iterate over the list of tuples, then concatenate the tuples? Maybe using some form of string formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
list = [' '.join(x) for x in tuples]
```

`join` is a string method that contatenates all items of a list (tuple) within a separator defined in `''` brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list = [ '{0} {1}'.format(t[0],t[1]) for t in tuples ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to use both values of a tuple, you can use something like this:

```
my_list = []
for (first, second) in tuples:
    my_list.append(first+ ' '+ second)
```

In this case

```
my_list = [' '.join(x) for t in tuples]
```

should be fine

Answer (score 0):

tuples = [('hello', 'my'), ('my', 'name'), ('name', 'is'), ('is', 'bob')]
result=[]
[result.append(k+" "+v) for k,v in tuples]

```
print(result)
```

output:

```
['hello my', 'my name', 'name is', 'is bob']
```